Localize an angular library
The Angular i18n docs are clear about localizing an app, but it does not say anything about libraries.
I've checked the Angular library too, and it's not saying anything about localization.
So where are we at the moment about this subject ? I've found this topic but it's closed since 2021, and I don't really like the solution since we don't work with i18n extraction but custom id.
How can I translate my angular library so it uses the locale of the project using it ?

I think it's pretty simple, just add i18n tag in your library HTML element and it should work. I will need more information to help you.
